# How to change Laravel Homestead version constraints

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

Trying to update to the latest Laravel Homestead version.  The documentation says to update composer json as follows: `"laravel/homestead": "^11"`

I use a single box for all my development, so I presume it means the composer.json in the Homestead directory.  When I add this line to that file, I get the following error message:

```
Root package 'laravel/homestead' cannot require itself in its composer.json
```

When I run `vagrant box list` I get the following output:

```
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 9.5.1)
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 9.6.0)
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 10.0.0)
```

As far as I know, this means that I am running Homestead V10.0.0.

So, how do I update to Version 11?

Comment: What is the value of `name` in your `composer.json`?

Comment: laravel/homestead

Comment: That's your answer. Change the `name` in `composer.json` and the `laravel/homestead` will be able to _require_ itself into it.

Answer (score 0):

check inside homestead.rb (inside the Homestead folder) and check for this line

```rb
config.vm.box_version = settings['version']
```

(should be at line 22)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
For example elaborating what should be checked and how it should be changed might help.